# How to stack arrays and scalars in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list of numpy vectors (1-D arrays) or scalars (i.e. just numbers). All the vectors have the same length but I don't know what that is. I need to `vstack` all the elements to create one matrix (2-D array) in such a way that the scalars are treated as vectors having the scalar at each position.

Example is the best description:

Case 1:

```
>>> np.vstack([np.array([1, 2, 3]), np.array([3, 2, 1])])
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [3, 2, 1]])
```

Case 2:

```
>>> np.vstack([1, 2])
array([[1],
       [2]])
```

Case 3:

```
>>> np.vstack([np.array([1, 2, 3]), 0, np.array([3, 2, 1])])
np.array([[1, 2, 3],
          [0, 0, 0],
          [3, 2, 1]])
```

Cases 1 and 2 work out-of-the-box. In case 3, however, it does not as vstack needs all the elements to be arrays of the same length.

Is there some nice way (preferably one-liner) of achieving this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could [create broadcast object](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast.html#numpy.broadcast), and call `np.column_stack` on that:

```
In [175]: np.column_stack(np.broadcast([1, 2, 3], 0, [3, 2, 1]))
Out[175]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [3, 2, 1]])
```

Alternatively, you could ask NumPy to [literally broadcast](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast_arrays.html#numpy.broadcast_arrays) the items to compatibly-shaped arrays:

```
In [158]: np.broadcast_arrays([1, 2, 3], [3, 2, 1], 0)
Out[158]: [array([1, 2, 3]), array([3, 2, 1]), array([0, 0, 0])]
```

and then call `vstack` or `row_stack` on that:

```
In [176]: np.row_stack(np.broadcast_arrays([1, 2, 3], 0, [3, 2, 1]))
Out[176]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [3, 2, 1]])
```

Of these two options (using `np.broadcast` or `np.broadcast_arrays`),
`np.broadcast` is quicker since you don't actually need to instantiate the
broadcasted sub-arrays.

One limitation of `np.broadcast`, however, is that it can accept at most 32
arguments. In that case, use `np.broadcast_arrays`.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I'm looking for. Just a small question (just out of curiosity): in the first case (with ``broadcast``), why does ``column_stack`` put the elements in rows instead of columns? If I had no scalars and omitted the ``broadcast`` the vectors would be in columns instead of rows. It's like the ``broadcast`` transposes the result.

Comment: @zegkljan: `np.broadcast` returns an iterator. That iterator returns tuples consisting of
values from each of the original arrays (or scalars) that would be grouped
together for element-wise operations. Look at
what `list(np.broadcast(np.arange(24).reshape(2,3,4), np.arange(3*4).reshape(3,4)))` returns. It is a 24-element list of 2-tuples. It is not showing the individual broadcasted arrays like `np.broadcast_arrays` does. It is showing the element-wise pairings. Given the nature of the iterator returned by `np.broadcast`, `np.column_stack` is required to form the desired array.

Comment: `np.array(list(np.broadcast(....))` is faster than `np.vstack(np.broadcast(...))`.  It doesn't have to pass the arrays through `np.atleast_2d`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is to fill the gap between the readable python world, and the efficient numpy world.

Experimentally, python is paradoxically often better that numpy for this task. With `l=[ randint(10) if n%2 else randint(0,10,100) for n in range(32)]` :

```
In [11]: %timeit array([x if type(x) is ndarray else [x]*100 for x in l])
1000 loops, best of 3: 655 µs per loop

In [12]: %timeit column_stack(broadcast(*l))
100 loops, best of 3: 3.77 ms per loop
```

Furthermore broadcast is limited to 32 elements.

Answer (score -1):

Not a one liner, but you can fill an empty array with your scalar.

```
>>> a = np.empty(4, dtype=int )
>>> a.fill(2)
>>> print(a)
[2 2 2 2]
```